# Как убрать дыру?

Tags: php

Есть сайт на котором доступны только все символы кроме английских, проверял так

```
$text = mb_ereg_replace("[zA-Za]", null, $_GET['text']);
```

но в базе увидел, что есть английские символы! Как сделать так, чтобы уже 100% никто ничего не писал на англ языку?

Answer (score 2):

Ваше выражение пропускает все буквы в диапазоне `b .. y`. Напишите правильно выражение.

```
$text = mb_ereg_replace("[A-Za-z]", null, $_GET['text']);
```

Comment: Вот спасибо) а это можно как то обойти? или это уже 100% вариант что его не обойти?

Comment: 100% я не дам. Вот всякие буквы с умляутами вполне пройдут. Но нужны ли они?

На будущее - вынесите такой код в отдельную функцию. И создайте себе тестовый файл, где будете прогонять с разными входными данными (это называется юнит тестирование, вариант для бедных:) ). И на будущее не будет неожиданных ситуаций.